# Hikvision IP-camera activation

Tags: isapi, onvif, hikvision

From couple of years Hikvision doesn't provide new IP cameras with defaults password for some strange security reasons and new user is forced to set unique password via web interface. In my case I need to activate hundreds of cameras and it will take too much time to do it via web.

I tried to make it via ONVIF SetUSers (http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/SetUser), but recieved:

```
ONVIFError: Unknown error: (401, u'Unauthorized')
```

Also i tried ISAPI protocol with /ISAPI/Security/users, but also no luck without any response at all.
Of course, after activation ONVIF and ISAPI work fine.
Is it any alternative way to automate activation process?

Answer (score 1):

Hikvision provides "Batch Configuration" software.
https://us.hikvision.com/en/support-resources/downloads/tools

Answer (score 0):

You cannot activate automatically. But you can use sadptool to set it up easily. if the cameras come with a preset password, they could cause security vulnerabilities. Because many people are setting up cameras with the default password. This is a very time-consuming process but there is no other way.

Comment: We have like 200+ cameras to activate, so it is really time consuming process. I succeeded to make some stupid but working automation via selenium.